# Error in using max function with Armadillo sparse matrices

Tags: c++, armadillo

Here is the code that I am getting error(type mismatch) on line no. with `max`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<armadillo>  

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    umat loc;
    loc<<0<<0<<3<<endr
       <<2<<4<<4<<endr;

    vec val={1,2,3};
    sp_mat m(loc,val);

    double t=arma::max(sum(square(m),1)) + 1.0;
    cout<<t<<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody tell me why is that error happening and how to get around this.
Note: `cout<<max(sum(square(m),1))` prints the result to console but adding any number to the output flags error.

Comment: What error? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I tried looking up the data type returned by calling `sum` with a sparse matrix (since that ought to be the key to your problem).  But the Armadillo doc I found only describes calling `sum` with a vector or a dense matrix.  Where is the documentation you used that describes `sum` on a sparse matrix?

Comment: @JSF  [link](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) describes how to use basic functions with sp_mat.

Comment: @YSC. Error is quite big. here is the summary ` mismatched types ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’ and ‘double’. Basically mismatch type error. But I could not figure out why is that although `max` function output can be printed on console but could not be assigned to scalar.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert a 1x1 matrix into a pure scalar (like double), use the [as_scalar()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#as_scalar) function. Same goes for any Armadillo expression that results in a 1x1 matrix.

It's a good idea to read the [Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) thoroughly before posting questions on Stackoverflow.

Modifying your example:

```
umat loc = { { 0, 0, 3 },
             { 2, 4, 4 } };

vec val = {1, 2, 3};

sp_mat m(loc,val);

m.print("m:");

max(sum(square(m),1)).print("expression:");

double t = as_scalar( max(sum(square(m),1)) );

cout << t << endl;
```

Comment: It's not always possible to look through the doc completely,e.g. boost documentation is too huge to go through all the functions and then start coding will take a long time to yield something useful. At night, I got the same idea of converting 1x1 matrix into scalar but did not know how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us (and I can't find in the documentation) exactly what data type is returned by `arma::max(sum(square(m),1))`

You have tested that whatever it is does **not** implicitly convert to `double` and whatever it is can be sent to a `stream` and when that is done it looks like a `double`.

My **guess** is it is something that can be explicitly converted to double so try:

`(double)arma::max(sum(square(m),1)) + 1.0`

The documentation shows the returned value for a dense matrix being used to initialize a `double` so that is obviously a type than can be explicitly converted to `double`.  I had initially missed the thing you linked for me effectively saying `sum` does something on sparse matrix compatible with what it does on dense.  So you can almost conclude (rather than just guess) that `max(sum(m))` should be the same type (explicitly convertible to `double`).

If that doesn't work, we will really need a full quote of the error message, not just a summary of what it seems to mean.

Now that we have an error message, we can see this is a flaw in Armadillo's template metaprogramming:

Operations are stacked in template meta programming in order to avoid creating excess temporary objects.  Then the meta programming must resolve the whole mess when the result is used.

If this is a minor flaw in the meta programming, you could add just one trivial temporary to fix it:

```
double t = arma::max(sum(square(m),1));
cout << t+1.0 endl;
```

But you probably already tried that.  So you may need more temporaries and you probably need to give them exact correct types (rather than use `auto`).  My first guess would be:

```
colvec v = sum(square(m),1);
```

Then see what works with `arma::max(v)`

(Earlier I made a negative comment on an answer that suggested starting with `auto` temporaries for each step.  That answer was deleted.  It wasn't far wrong.  But I'd still say it was wrong to start there without seeing the template meta-programming failures and likely, though I'm not sure, wrong to use `auto` to try to bypass a meta-programming failure.)

Comment: I told you that error is too big to fit even in my terminal. There seems to be some sort of type mismatch. I did the type cast trick but it does not solve the prob. You can reproduce the error by running on linux machine with armadillo.

Comment: after type casting error  is: ` invalid cast from type ‘arma::enable_if2<true, const arma::SpOp<arma::SpOp<arma::SpOp<arma::SpMat<double>, arma::spop_square>, arma::spop_sum>, arma::spop_max> >::result {aka const arma::SpOp<arma::SpOp<arma::SpOp<arma::SpMat<double>, arma::spop_square>, arma::spop_sum>, arma::spop_max>}’ to type ‘double’
 double t=(double)arma::max(sum(square(m),1)) + 1.0;
                                            ^
`

Comment: with `colvec v = sum(square(m),1);` the same conversion error is coming.

Comment: The failure is in that initialization of `v`, not in the later use of `v`?

Comment: in the initialization of `v`.

Comment: The catch that I found is that `+` and `-` operations are not working on sparse matrices while `*` and `/` is working which contradicts  what doc of Armadillo says. Strange.